# Is dragging and dropping flles and URIs into web browsers possible?

Tags: javascript, browser, drag-and-drop, file-manager

Is dragging and dropping files from the desktop, and URLs from different browsers onto a control on a web browser supported, at least in some web browsers?

I want to be able to drop a URL or file onto a DOM element and take some action on it.

Comment: yeah, that's possible. maybe not in old IE, but i think it too had some wierd DND routine of it's own. but for any recent browser, yes. search html5 drag and drop to find a million demos.

Comment: @dandavis is almost correct. HTML5 supports [drag and drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) but that's not exactly what you want (although you may use it). What you really want is [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/).  Here is a [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and a [demo](http://html5demos.com/file-api).

Comment: @JaredGotte: what's not correct ? File's can come from dataTransfers on the event object resulting from a drop event. -1 for the w3Fools link...